# Exporting JSON response to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, web-scraping, export-to-excel

How can I export my scraped data into a CSV file. My code below prints out all of the data correctly, but I would like to export it the same way to a CSV file, line by line.

How can I write the data to a csv file?

```
import requests
import json
import csv

with open('Links.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in readCSV:
    data = row[0]

    for b in row:
        r = requests.get(b)
        json_object = json.loads('{"data":%s}}' % (r.content.decode("utf-8").replace("jQuery111002521088376353553_1491736907010(", "")[:-2].replace("\'", "")))
        for game in json_object["data"]["docs"]:
            print ("Name: %s, Price: %s, CatalogId: %s, slug: %s" % (game["name"], game["minPrice"], game["catalogId"], game["slug"]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the data to a row in a csv file like:

```
writeCSV.writerow([game["name"], game["minPrice"], game["catalogId"], game["slug"]])
```

Here is this added to your code, with the init code needed:

```
import csv
import json
import requests

with open('Links.csv', 'r') as r_csvfile, open('outp.csv', 'w') as w_csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(r_csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writeCSV = csv.writer(w_csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writeCSV.writerow("Name Price CatalogId slug".split())

    for row in readCSV:
        data = row[0]

        for b in row:
            r = requests.get(b)
            json_object = json.loads('{"data":%s}}' % (
                r.content.decode("utf-8").replace(
                    "jQuery111002521088376353553_1491736907010(", "")[:-2]
                    .replace("\'", "")))
            for game in json_object["data"]["docs"]:
                writeCSV.writerow([game["name"], game["minPrice"],
                                   game["catalogId"], game["slug"]])
```

You did not give any actual data, so I could not test this, but it will be close.

Answer (score 0):

I think pandas is the package you‘re looking for.
Use pandas.dataframe.from_dict or pandas.dataframe.from_json. Once you have your pandas dataframe writing a csv file is as easy as it gets.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html